# Bootstrap not correctly working with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-5

## Hello everyone

I start a new rails app with this [starter template](https://github.com/lewagon/rails-templates) and when i add a simple navbar from bootstrap.

its look like this
[image]

The principal problem is that JS is not working, the dropdown menus doesn't work and the searchnar is not in his correct position.

I'm using rails 7.0.4 and ruby 3.1.2p20 and

It should be like this
[image]

Comment: Check if bootstrap js is loading from application.rb or check on chrome inspect

Comment: you can follow these instructions, this is the latest version of rails 7.0.4 and ruby 3.1.0  https://mixandgo.com/learn/ruby-on-rails/how-to-install-bootstrap?utm_source=rubyflow&utm_medium=organic&utm_campaign=bootstrap_rails7&utm_content=

Comment: I ran into the same issue, I mistakenly added a navbar from bootstrap 4 but imported bootstrap 5, just replace the correct code snippet, it should resolve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thast's a bit shame but all the problem was that i was using the wrong version of bootstrap template.
I'm not working in this project anymore so don't have access to the versions that makes me write this help request but i remember what was causing the "problem".

Let's supose that we start a new application:

```
rails new YOUR_APP_NAME --css=bootstrap
```

Rails will generate a *.package.json* File where you can see the bootsrap version
[image]

My problem was that i went to [bootstrap page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) with the wrong version and if you do this some styles and js features that comes with the bootstrap library won't work correctly.

Always remember to check what version do you have in your package.json and search this version in bootsrap page.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).